# How to select all objects in the entire document?

Tags: adobe-indesign, selections

I need to select all elements in the document so that I can perform actions on all of them (don't ask me which actions, please). CTRL+A selects only elements on the spread but I need all pages.

Comment: this is might help [https://www.rorohiko.com/wordpress/task-tools-for-adobe-indesign/](https://www.rorohiko.com/wordpress/task-tools-for-adobe-indesign/)

Comment: I'd like to jump ahead a bit and ask: What is it that you need to get done, that requires you to select everything in every single page?

Comment: I dont know how you expect someone to help you without understanding what you're doing.  Instead of being so isolated in your question I assure you that you may get a better answer and possibly some scripting help if you can define the process you are performing but telling us not to ask.. well Im a rebel..  so Im going to ask..  What are you doing that would require you to select everything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's my experience and understanding that each page in Indesign is it's own object. I know of no feature or tool which allows you to select elements across pages. Selection is restricted to the current page or spread only.

If you think about it, this makes sense because it would be exceptionally rare that one would need to select elements on more than one page. At least select them for use in any useful manner.

Without knowing *exactly* what it is you are trying to do there may be a few things you can use:

- Create an action and run the action on every page rather than trying to do it all at once. It's quite possible that whatever you need to do is a simple set up for an action. Needing to manually step through pages to run an action is generally a better use of time than trying to find an exceptionally custom solution to work with entire documents.
- Try scripting. Scripting can often "walk" through a document where actions really can't.
- Reconfigure your document to use Master Pages and Layers correctly. This way you only need to edit common items in one or two locations rather than on every page.

Comment: InDesign, she don' have no actions. One day, maybe. We can hope!